Proof that the sequence of cesaro means converges to the same limit as the sequence.
The question is: Show that if $(x_n)$ is a convergent sequence, then the sequence given by the averages $y_{n}=\frac{(x_{1}+x_{2}+...+x_{n})}{n}$ also converges to the same limit.
We know $|x_{n}-x_{0}| < \epsilon, \forall  n\geq N_{0}(\epsilon)$. Fix $m\geq N_{0}$, and let n be arbitrary.  Now, $y_{n} = \frac{x_{1}+x_{2}+...x_{m-1}}{n}+\frac{x_{m}+x_{m+1}+...+x_{n}}{n-m+1} (\frac{n-m+1}{n})$, so that $|y_{n} - x_{0}|= |\frac{x_{1}+x_{2}+...x_{m-1}}{n}+\frac{x_{m}+x_{m+1}+...+x_{n}}{n-m+1} (\frac{n-m+1}{n})-x_{0}|$ (*). Now, (xn) is convergent, so all $x_{n}s$ are finite. Thus for $n\geq N_{1}$, $\frac{x_{m}+x_{m+1}+...+x_{n}}{n-m+1} < \epsilon$. Observe that $lim\frac{n-m+1}{n} = 1$. This is justified, since $|\frac{n-m+1}{n}-1|<\epsilon \Leftrightarrow n-m+1 <n+n\epsilon \Leftrightarrow \frac{-m+1}{n}<\epsilon$. We can select an $N_{2}$ such that for n > $N_{2}$ the inequality is satisfied. Now, for $n\geq max\left \{ N_{0},N_{1},N_{2} \right \},$ we have that all conditions are satisfied, thus$|y_{n}-x_{0}| \lt |\epsilon+\frac{x_{m}+x_{m+1}+...+x_{n}}{n-m+1} -x_{0}|\lt\epsilon+|\frac{x_{m}+x_{m+1}+...+x_{n}}{n-m+1} -x_{0}|\lt2\epsilon.$ Thus we have that (yn) converges to $x_{0}$, the limit of $x_n$.
Is my proof justified? Specifically, I have a question about the part where I plug in 1 for the expression $\frac{n-m+1}{n}$. Would more details need to be provided for me to justify this step? Thank you so much for your attention and participation.

Your proof may be invalid in:

for $n \geq N_1, \frac{x_m + \dots + x_n}{n - m + 1} < \varepsilon$.

That's because:

$(x_n)$ might be negative, so inequality above does not necessarily hold.
$\frac{x_m + \dots + x_n}{n - m + 1}$ goes to $x_0$ ($n \to \infty$), so you have to evaluate the difference between $\frac{x_m + \dots + x_n}{n - m + 1}$ and $x_0$.

Instead of showing the original statement of the question, it may be easier and simpler to show that
$$ if \lim_{n \to \infty}x'_n = 0, then \lim_{n \to \infty} y'_n = \frac{\sum_{k=1}^n x'_k}{n} = 0.$$
If we take $x'_n = x_n - x_0$, new statement tells us that $y'_n = \frac{\sum_{k=1}^n (x_k - x_0)}{n} = \frac{\sum_{k=1}^n x_k}{n} - x_0 \to 0$.
